# Qt Creator doesn't recognize Qt3D

Tags: qt-creator, qml, qt3d

I've just build and installed QtQuick3D on my machine. I run the example project "cube". 
It works I can build and execute it. It shows me a cube that I can rotate with my mouse. But i the  QML-editor I get errors on all Viewport and Item3D types.  It feels as if Creator doesn't recognize the module (import work though).
When hovering over Cube i get the "hint": Could not resolve the prototype Item3D of Cube

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vke5f.png]

Is there some setting i've forgot, or what can I do?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue doesn't exist as of QtCreator 3.2.1 + Qt 5.3 + Qt3D 1.0 (built and installed from source) on Ubuntu 14.04:

[image]